# No such file or directory but the file exists

Tags: java

I'm not completely done with this program but after running it IntelliJ keeps telling me no file exists even though it does. What am I doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class NumberTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
        Boolean prime;
        Boolean even;
        Boolean repeatsDigits;
        int num;
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("numbers2.txt"));
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("numberSummary.txt");
        outputFile.printf("%15s", "Repeat\n");
        outputFile.printf("Number");
        outputFile.printf("%8s", "Digits");
        outputFile.printf("%8s", "Even");
        outputFile.printf("%8s", "Prime");

        num = inputFile.nextInt();
        
        outputFile.close();
```

Comment: This has to do with the classpath from where you are trying to read the file. if the file is there in src/main/resources, supply that as the in the file name as well

Comment: Im sorry I don't understand what that means. I'm pretty new to java. I have the file on my computer in my downloads folder. Do I have to put the file somewhere else or am I modifying my code?

Comment: If your file is in downloads then you have to specify the complete path of the file ex: c:\downloads\numbers2.txt

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the relative path to the file. In this case, I needed to add a "/" before the numbers2.txt as the program was in the same directory as this file.